# Adding Product to category programmatically getting error in Magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, category-products

When I am adding the product to a category I am getting below error :

> "Category does not contain specified product"

The error comes from the below file :

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/CategoryLinkRepository.php in deleteByIds()

My observer listen to `catalog_product_save_after` in order to add the product to sale category based on price:

```
$categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
array_push($categoryIds,$categoryidfromsettings);
$CategoryLinkRepository->assignProductToCategories($_product->getSku(), $categoryIds);
```

Comment: Can you show us the code of your observer for `catalog_product_save_after`?

Comment: @nicolallias 
$categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
array_push($categoryIds,$categoryidfromsettings);
$CategoryLinkRepository->assignProductToCategories($_product->getSku(), $categoryIds);

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of the mismatch between categories returned by the `$product->getCategoryIds();` which won't have the new category you have added and `$productResource->getCategoryIds($product)` which will have it. `src/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/CategoryLinkManagement.php:95` is where it all goes wrong.

You can fix it by adding `$product->setCategoryIds($categoryIds);` line to your code.